# Como impedir valores repetidos?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax, css3

Olá, sou novo ainda em desenvolvimento e estou precisando validar campos inputs, mais precisamente impedir que os inputs de uma mesma coluna dentro de uma tabela tenha valores repetidos.

Exemplo html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Navegador em tabela HTML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="dados">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Código</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="idcodFab" name="cfabri"class="codFab" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="idcodFab" name="cfabri"class="codFab" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="idcodFab" name="cfabri"class="codFab" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<input type="submit" class="Cenviar" value="Enviar" id="00007667" />
</body>
</html>
```

Desde já, agradeço toda ajuda.

Comment: Pode experimentar o código que lhe deixo aqui.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nucge8b4/13/)

1º Precisa de dar id diferente nos input's
2º use Jquery